# OOB Facebook login feature is not working in AEM 6.2

Tags: facebook, aem

I am trying to achieve social login in AEM 6.2. OOB it's already implemented for facebook and twitter,but when I tested it on geometrix site it's working only for twitter. For Facebook, it's redirecting back to the login page with authentication failed message.

FYI >> I am testing it on publish instance only and 
Granite OAuth Authentication Handler SErvice is also enabled

If anyone has faced the same problem and resolved it, Please share.

Comment: If it is an issue with OOTB AEM 6.2 installation that can be reproduced easily and consistently then it qualifies for a DC ticket anyway so you can talk to Adobe about this. They will be in a better position to fix it.

Comment: Hi Pooja I am trying to achieve something similar to your question, if you could have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978016/social-sharing-in-adobe-experience-manager-aem . Thanks